# Can PHP use a MySQL bookmarked Query?

Tags: php, mysql

I haven't found anything that matches my situation...

I am using XAMPP, which has MySQL as a backend and PHP in the front (web) end.  in the Administration screen of MySQL (phpMyAdmin) I can create and run SQL requests.  There is also an option of "Bookmark this SQL Query: "

Suppose i save a "Bookmark SQL Query".  Is it possible for PHP to reference this Bookmark SQL Query?  or do I have to create that query in PHP.  It would be easier to reference the Bookmarked query, rather than make the full SQL query

Thanks.

Thanks to those who understood the question.  You are smarter than those to didn't.

Comment: Are you asking about a `VIEW`?

Comment: or `Stored Procedures`?

Comment: what do you want to do... explain correctly

Comment: ...or the `Bookmark this SQL query` thing from phpMyAdmin?

Comment: The impression I get when Googling for that term is that it is a feature of your SQL client that allows you to save a query for later. If that is right then, no, you can't because PHP doesn't interface with your client, it has its own client.

Comment: It might be possible to retrieve the query from the `pma_bookmark` table in the `phpmyadmin` database, then execute it, though I wouldn't do it. You would still have to have the query to retrieve the query in your PHP code.

Comment: Thanks for quick responses.  sorry I didn't explain it well.  I inherited the software and i'm fairly new to it.  I am in PHPMyAdmin,  SQL Tab.  there's a field for "Bookmark this SQL Query" where I can enter a name the SQL string/results.  that "bookmark" query is what I want to access through PHP.  Does that help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, I don't think it's possible, the feature you're talking about is a feature in the client application only. You should write the query in PHP. That way you don't have to rely on an external feature/query for the application to work either.

Comment: Agreed.  Relying on this "bookmarked" query for your application to work is a poor choice.  Your application should be self contained and not base core functionality/queries on functionality provided by 3rd parties.

Answer (score 2):

PHPMyAdmin is simply a PHP application that interfaces with your database. Anything you save on it stays on it. 
Your PHP application is completely different from PHPMyAdmin and unless you create such a feature, you cannot use it within your application. 
If you create a SQL execution interface within your application, you can also create something like that to be able to re-use the query. 
 
Hope the explanation makes sense and the answer helps.